# FlashDevelop - Compiled SWF/HTML does not work in IE9

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, internet-explorer-9, flash, flashdevelop

I have the most weirdest problem with Flash Player and FlashDevelop (to be honest, dont know which one causes it), so let me explain.

I have recently downloaded FlashDevelop and created an AS3 Project.
When I compile the project, the files are generated in the **bin** folder. Now, when I navigate to the bin folder and open the **index.html** in Firefox and IE9, everything works fine.

However, when I copy the **bin** folder somewhere else and then try to do the same, i can see the flash movie in Firefox but not IE9!!!!!!!

I would appreciate it if someone could explain as to why this happens. 
If you would like to take a look at the files, here is the link http://www.4shared.com/zip/qZgeaEOm/bin.html

Also, I am running Windows 7 (64-bit).
and a screen shot of the *Project* > *Properties* http://www.4shared.com/photo/r_AzjY9o/FlashDevelop_Project_Propertie.html

Comment: Can you specify the locations where you try to open the `index.html` in IE9? I suspect it's some kind of freaky security sandbox problem. And I assume by "not working" you mean that the movie is not shown at all?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right FlashPlayer in IE9 and it's not disabled? Tell us what www.playerversion.com says.

Comment: aaaidan, I copied the bin folder to my C:\ directory and then I tried to open index.html in IE9. When I open it in IE9, it gets "loaded" I believe, because when I right-click on where the flash movie is supposed to be, I get the Flash Player context menu ("Settings", "Global Settings", etc), but I can not see the actual movie being played. However, when I open the same index.html with Firefox , I can see the movie.

Comment: Mark, I will check that tonight. but when I go to Adobe.com and check my Flash player, it says that I have the most recent version installed. Also I dont think it is related to flash player version, because I can see the flash movie in IE9 when I open index.html in its original directory (under FlashDevelop project directory). The problem happens when I copy the **bin** folder somewhere else, e.g. C:\, and then try to view the index.html.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**

The problem was with the Adobe security sandbox. My .swf file loads an XML to build up a menu; however, the local access is restricted, and that is why when I move the bin folder, i am not able to see the movie clip. When I run the .swf by itself, it gave me this error:

```
***SecurityError:** Error **#2148**: SWF file file:///C|/Users/bashir/Desktop/AutoMenu.swf cannot access local resource file:///C|/Users/bashir/Desktop/Menu.xml.
Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources.
    at flash.net::URLStream/load()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/load()
    at MenuCreator()[C:\Users\bashir\Documents\FlashDevWorkspace\AutoMenu\src\MenuCreator.as:30]
    at Main/init()[C:\Users\bashir\Documents\FlashDevWorkspace\AutoMenu\src\Main.as:44]
    at Main()[C:\Users\bashir\Documents\FlashDevWorkspace\AutoMenu\src\Main.as:29]*
```

The solution was to add the target folder to the trusted locations in **Flash Player** Global Settings. To do this, just open a flash file in the browser, and then right-click and choose `Global Settings > Advanced > Trusted Location Settings > Add` , then add the target folder. When you upload the flash movie to the web, you wont have the security sandbox problem, only when you want to view it locally , you have to do this :D.